# select all elements of class and iterate over each even object (nth child (even) replacement)

Tags: javascript, css, quirks-mode

I'm displaying the alphabet with each letter having the same background (width 31px ). I need half of the letters to have a width of 30px.  This is handled by:

```
div.alpha:nth-child(even) {width: 30px;}
```

However, this does not work in ie because of the pseudo compatibility issues.

I'm looking for a pure javascript alternative that works with ie **IN quirks mode**.

I tried:

```
function letterwidth () {
    var a = document.querySelectorAll ('div.alphabet');
    for (var i = 0, b = a.length; i < b; i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            a[i].style.width = '30px';
        }
    }
}
```

but I get an error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll'

Comment: I know in another comment you said you don't want to bring in jQuery,but what about just its selector engine sizzle? http://sizzlejs.com/

Answer (score 1):

If `querySelector` isn't supported by the browser, you'll need to use regular DOM traversal methods :

```
var el  = [],
    div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i=0; i<div.length; i++) {
    if (div[i].className.indexOf('alphabet') != -1) 
        el.push(div[i]);
}

for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0)
         el[i].style.width = '30px';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8uNYg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using an old version of Internet Explorer that does not support `document.querySelectorAll`

[Browsers where you can use `querySelectorAll`](http://caniuse.com/queryselector).

Comment: I'm using ie9, but the site is coded horribly and thus is not displayed correctly unless in quirks mode.

Comment: I know what quirks mode is, my problem is that it HAS to be in quirks mode to run properly without re-coding quite a bit

Answer (score 0):

`Object doesn't support property or method 'querySelectorAll'`

Obsolete browser.

jQuery is pure JavaScript. So unless you want to rewrite the selector parser yourself to finally get something similar to the one from jQuery, i suggest you directly use it.

Comment: I know, I would typically do this with jquery but I didn't want to bring it in just for this if I didn't have to.